# How to fix Gradle sync error in Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.3

How do I fix a Gradle sync error in Android Studio (latest version 2.3)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the gradle version is not compatible. Please update your gradle version in project level build.gradle to 2.3.

```
buildscript {
...
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}
}
```